# How to delete lines & populate based on particluar field in unix

Tags: unix, gawk, nawk, awk

I want to delete lines based on "CLIENT TOTAL" and the succeeding unit lines untill next name.
The number of unit lines(i.e lines with 30.0 and 15.0) after "CLIENT TOTAL" line may vary untill the next name.
Most importantly the file is not delimited.
Given below is my input file.
INPUT:

RELATIVITY/O F   32629 DT MBSA
HALL             15.0             5,850
HALL             30.0            21,650
RELATIVITY/O F   34145 DT MBSA
HALL             30.0            10,850
*CLIENT TOTAL RELATIVITY/O F     38,350
                 30.0            32,500
                 15.0             5,850
PFIZER           96607 DT MBSA
HALL             15.0            32,700
HALL             30.0            21,300
PFIZER           96609 DT MBSA
HALL             60.0            30,200
HALL             75.0           182,100
HALL             90.0            67,700
*CLIENT TOTAL PFIZER            334,000
                 90.0            67,700
                 30.0            21,300
                 15.0            32,700

I want my output as below.
OUTPUT:

RELATIVITY/O F   32629 DT MBSA
HALL             15.0             5,850
HALL             30.0            21,650
RELATIVITY/O F   34145 DT MBSA
HALL             30.0            10,850
PFIZER           96607 DT MBSA
HALL             15.0            32,700
HALL             30.0            21,300
PFIZER           96609 DT MBSA
HALL             60.0            30,200
HALL             75.0           182,100
HALL             90.0            67,700

Comment: Do you REALLY want that intermediate output/input file or do you just want to convert your first input file above to your last output file?

Comment: I want the last OUTPUT for my very first INPUT.

Comment: Then why not clean up your question to show that so those reading it don't waste their time?

Answer (score 1):

Through awk,

```
$ awk '$1=="-----"{x=0} NF==1{x=1}x' file
34567
20.0    5,678
20.0    5,678
20.0    5,678
20.0    5,678
20.0    5,678
78545
20.0    41,424
20.0    41,424
30.0    41,424
```

It skips the lines which contains `-----` in the column 1 upto the line in which the whole line`$0` is equivalent to  column 1 `$1`.

Update:

```
$ awk 'NF==1{print; var=$1}NF==2{print var"   "$2}' file
34567
34567   5,678
34567   5,678
34567   5,678
34567   5,678
34567   5,678
78545
78545   41,424
78545   41,424
78545   41,424
```

Comment: `$0==$1` is an odd way to test if there's just one field. `NF==1` would be more natural. What if `$1` contained `3` and `$2` contained `0`? Awk would probably do a numeric comparison and then `$0==$1` would be true despite there being 2 fields.

Comment: Hi Ed and Avinash,....The above code doesnt work if there is null value in field 2, it will populate wrong id in field 1... so i will be thankful if you correct the above code....@Avinash Raj and @Ed Morton

Comment: What do mean by a "null value in field 2"? Are your files tab-separated or fixed-width fields or something else? Update your question to clarify and update your sample input/expected output to show that case.

Comment: My file is tab delimited and suppose if my field 2 doesnt have any value, according to the above code it will populate wrong id like 20.0 or 30.0 in field1... but i want my id (five digit) to pupulate in field 1 even if field 2 is null...@Ed Morton

Comment: @Praveenkumar - SERIOUSLY, update your question! Doling out these little snippets of info in comments in various locations, and having your posted question not contain the latest info and have an example that doesn't contain the test case(s) you actually have and care about is frustrating for those of us trying to help you, especially when you keep ignoring requests to simply update your question.

Comment: @Praveenkumar I just posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" }
/^[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]*$/ { id = $1; inRec = 1 }
/^-/  { inRec = 0 }
inRec { print id, $2 }
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
25333
98275
98275   68,000
98275   149,000
98275   41,000
98275
98275   22,000
98275   162,000
25333
31932
31932   334,000
31932
31932   53,000
31932   47,000
```

Comment: `$` is a prompt. `tst.awk` is a file which contains an awk script starting with `BEGIN` and ending with `$2 }`. `cat tst.awk` is a command you execute to see the contents of the file `tst.awk`. Please get the book "Shell Scripting Recipes" by Chris Johnson to learn the basics of shell programming.

Comment: Well Ed...Thanks for suggesting the book as i am new to unix...Also the code is returning wrong output and i am not getting the above output... Its just returning field1 values and field2 is null...

Comment: It is impossible for that script to print field 1 values. Either your input file isn't as you've described (does `cat -v` show any control chars in it), or you did something wrong when copy/pasting the script, or your awk is broken (what OS are you on and what does `awk --version` output), or you are invoking it incorrectly. Beyond that, do the obvious thing and start adding debugging print statements to the script to figure out what's wrong. The script WILL produce the desired output if your input file is formatted as you say it is and you have a functional awk, as you can see above.

Comment: Do exactly what I did in my answer above and copy/paste the result into your question so we can see what you are executing, how you are executing it, and the output you are getting.

Comment: Hi Ed,  done with all type of debugging, file check up and scripting... but nothing is working on my way....I have once again edited the input file as above and it will be greatful if you can test the above file and look good or not....my awk version is 3.1.5.....@Ed Morton

Comment: The differences in your input now compared to previously are that it now has tabs after the 5-digit start-of-record ids and it no longer has a header line. I've updated my answer to match the new input format. By the way, that is a VERY old version of gawk, get a new one ASAP!

Comment: Hi Ed, Thanks a lot and now its working fine....thanks for your valuable time...i would be really thankful if you can please mail to me(praveen150cc@gmail.com) on what this code does, as it will be useful for me in future to modify up to my requirements...Most importantly i dont understand what the tst.awk function file does...Just a simple steps on what each line does would be grateful....Again @Ed Morton thanks for your time on it.

Comment: Praveen - You're welcome. Get the book "Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition" by Arnold Robbins, see if you can figure out the script and comment it yourself (it's only 4 lines long so I don't think it'll take you long) and feel free to ask questions.

Comment: Hi Ed, 
Thanks for suggesting some good books... 
Now i have modified my question... can u pls help me out...@Ed Morton